# Determining iphone upload/download speed programmatically

Tags: iphone, upload, networking, performance

How to get the iphones upload/download rates programmatically in order to be able to set upload chunk sizes and things of the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the speed on the phone or on the server?

If you want to calculate the speed on the phone, just set up a timer to download a file of known size, say 10kB or something.  You can then calculate the download rate.

Comment: Cool, yea i figured to do something like this, but I was asking jsut incase there was a better way to do it...Thanks for the reply